# Vega-lite: How to split one column into multiple rows

Tags: layout, visualization, vega-lite, vega

I would like to split one column into multiple rows.

[This is my code](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA28QAspQA4Gc4B6IgNwFMBzCAOkoEspNEAjG+gezKogFpIY+clHxEBEIkOhRU5XgHdy0TOWQ0AxvlIgAvgBoQAMwjrh8UOo6pEAWwB25o-XKowGAeRAGo9G+QCqdowYNhx2TF4gUACeuJ5wUeQ2uBzIEOg6+iD4ceqOqBDRqvAA2qDkdpZg9HaUjgAejhCUlMg8UPEgfhAOBq0ciLgs0aVdYREAugaGzq4YHckA+jY1kTFxGACOiD0+MD4UkRD19PjwxqhCWSMIIM2t7Z3dvSD9g8OjoeGYIFNOLm4EgtcMtjmtYp1trtGNB6IcDMdTud0lcsjYIMgANaOSyoVIYfAdFwsayeAz4egAL3iAFYAAx07wQjDqejIdSyNYcKw+XDwKDIRDkTJ6cqVDjVWoNJotNrUDohJQvN5DG4lMbfX7TWaAkDyGpuJkbBJQ8Iwg5ku4nM5wC5XAw3UD3OXQJ5KyIqj5wdVfSbagEYXBtVm4c2cF7rSE7M37OGWxE2u3C8lU+JO2WPRU9D3IAaqz7jH5-GYBhL6uxuLI9Sic27OzMJZ45vNen2FrX-OZlg26NEY7G3XH4hL4dJfcHG7JQtpcnn0PlwAVCkViqo1Oq3Rp1jPyt3Z-1dxJLdGNPq595qjV+qLMk3Rvaw+FWpG2lHJkCOu4711Z5Xn-PeleRYHrqwLLKsRpRtCsZPgmyKXO+9QAEwyg8u6-s2F4FpqxY6oGwbzmGYQTlBMaPvG1rwfaH4oduaE-o27pni2l6+sBna6uWho3pOpoPhaRyUa+CFZISuaYuQADq9BgBEdEugqjH7q8-6tkBHYloeYEniRWz3mGsFCUmIpdP2jiRhggqct43KoLy-KCsKOgTFkbT4FYhy3Pg6jpGmIBbiABrkHEFYVFAkQ3IFoUhWAYW9joQA)

It should be 3 months in each row like:

Jan Feb Mar

Apr Mai Jun

Jul Aug Sep

Oct Nov Dec

Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utiUO.png))

I try to use a layout with columns and rows, but it doesn´t work :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/seattle-weather.csv"
  },
  "transform": [
    {"timeUnit": "month", "field": "date", "as": "month"},
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {"op": "mean", "field": "temp_min", "as": "temp_min"},
        {"op": "mean", "field": "temp_max", "as": "temp_max"},
        {"op": "mean", "field": "precipitation", "as": "precipitation"},
        {"op": "mean", "field": "wind", "as": "wind"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["month"]
    }
  ],
  "columns": 3,
  "facet": {"field": "month", "type": "temporal"},
  "spec": {
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": {
          "color": "steelblue",
          "size": 500,
          "type": "circle",
          "tooltip": true
        },
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "temp_min", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null},
          "y": {"field": "temp_max", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null}
        }
      },
      {
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "wind", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null},
          "y": {"field": "precipitation", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null},
          "size": {"field": "wind"},
          "angle": {"field": "wind"}
        },
        "mark": {"color": "salmon", "type": "square", "tooltip": true}
      },
      {
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "temp_max", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null},
          "y": {"field": "temp_min", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null},
          "x2": {"field": "precipitation"},
          "y2": {"field": "wind"},
          "strokeWidth": {"field": "temp_max", "type": "quantitative"}
        },
        "mark": {"type": "rule", "tooltip": true}
      }
    ]
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "independent", "y": "independent"}}
}
```